# WSO2IS - How can i configure claims for service providers based on different user profiles?

Tags: wso2, claims, wso2-identity-server

In WSO2IS 5.7.0 I created a user with two profiles: Profile_A and Profile_B. Then I created two different Service Providers: App_A and App_B. 
Now I would like that during the authentication phase the claims of the Profilo_A are sent to the App_A and the claims of the profilo B are sent to the App_B.

Is it possible ? Which configuration should be applied?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this feature is not directly supported in WSO2 Identity Server, you have couple of options to get this done.

[a] If your intention is to send different set of claims to based on service provider, you can configure them under service provider claim configuration.

[b] If you intention is to send completely different user profile to different service providers, you can create multiple users for multiple profiles and associate them together by using the feature associate local profiles [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Associating+User+Accounts

IMO option [a] is good.